# error Matplotlib backend_wx and backend_wxagg require wxPython >=2.8

Tags: enthought

I have installed Enthought  in Amazon but I get this error 
Matplotlib backend_wx and backend_wxagg require wxPython >=2.8
when I run ipython --pylab.
How can I install wxpython2.9

I tried everything on the internet and it doesn't seem anything to work.

Comment: What OS? What is sys.prefix (in ipython)? Have you tried `ipython pylab=qt`?

Comment: it is in amazon which means it is under linux.

Comment: oh? https://aws.amazon.com/windows/

Comment: What is sys.prefix (in ipython)? Have you tried `ipython pylab=qt`?

Comment: ipython pylab=qt didn't work. I am not sure what you mean by "what is sys.prefix"